# PDF to XML conversion using PHP

Tags: php, xml, pdf

I need help to convert PDF to XML using PHP.
There are some sites which claims to do so. But they charge for that.
I have to write my own code in PHP for that.
Being a novice in PHP I don't know how to approach this task.
So if anyone had worked on it plz help me with this.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which schema? 'XML' is a bit vague - would you accept '<text>[entire contents of your pdf here]</text>' to be a reasonable output?

Comment: Hi @Bobby,
Thanks for quick response.
Actually I want to convert the contents of pdf to xml.
PDF content could be anything.
Then I need to convert that PDF to XML and then insert that XML data to mysql database.

I guess ur idea will also work.
Now u tell me if ur approach works for my case or not.
Even if it doesn't I might be able to extraxt some idea from ur approach.

Comment: My point is that you need to think a bit more carefully about what you're trying to do, and include some details in your question as to why you're trying to do it. Since PDF and XML are very different formats in their nature, converting between them is very difficult. For example, your PDF contains - laregly - formatting instructions. Your XML, conversely, contains semantic information. You will need to define - somehow - how to map between the two.

Comment: If all you're doing is inserting the PDF into the database, and not altering it or needing to get individual parts of it for any reason, perhaps you should be using a [BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) and don't worry about converting it to XML.

Comment: Well, I don't need to alter the PDF document but I do need individual parts of the PDF document. I will insert the individual parts to their respective columns. For example, say I would insert the image from PDF doc to one column and description to another.

Answer (score 0):

[PDF2HTML](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/) will convert to HTML or XML (using the -xml flag), but the result is a bit of a mess. You get lots of small chunks of information about the location of fragments of text. No good of you want to extract paragraphs or sections of text. You may be able to isolate images with a suitable XPath?

If you do need paragraphs or sections of text, it appears you have to do it heuristically. [Geert's blog](http://grtjn.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/pdf-to-xml-conversion-with-xslt-20.html) has an interesting approach:

> 1. Isolating text runs in different zones (like header and footer)
> 2. Gathering text runs on the same ‘line’ (ignoring columns here)
> 3. Translate indentation to hierarchy (helps finding lists, provides bare table/column handling)
> 4. Merging of lines to build paragraphs

Comment: Most interesting part of the code is available on github: https://github.com/grtjn/utilities/blob/master/enrich-pdf2html.xsl

Answer (score 0):

[PDFX](http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk/) does PDF-to-XML conversion and it's free to use. It might be helpful in your case as it can extract things like images and captions separately.

Example input/output can be found [here](http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk/example).

The [usage](http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk/usage) page includes a simple [PHP client example](http://pdfx.cs.man.ac.uk/serve/pdfx_client.php).

(Disclosure: It is my system.)

Comment: Could we see the source code? I would love to use this for a project, but host it on my server so that I can guarantee uptime.

Comment: Not open source at this time, sorry. Quite confident uptime will not be an issue, but feel free to get in touch if you'd like to talk things through.

Comment: @AlexConstantin ! this is no more working, can you please check again?

Comment: @atif I no longer maintain that endpoint, but plan on getting another host up soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class to pars pdf into string and than work this it =)

```
<?php class PDF2Text2 {
var $multibyte = 4; //
var $convertquotes = ENT_QUOTES; //
var $showprogress = true; //
var $filename = '';
var $decodedtext = '';

function setFilename($filename) {
    // Reset
    $this->decodedtext = '';
    $this->filename = $filename;
}

function output($echo = false) {
    if($echo) echo $this->decodedtext;
    else return $this->decodedtext;
}

function setUnicode($input) {
    // 4 for unicode. But 2 should work in most cases just fine
    if($input == true) $this->multibyte = 4;
    else $this->multibyte = 2;
}

function decodePDF() {
    // Read the data from pdf file
    $infile = @file_get_contents($this->filename, FILE_BINARY);
    if (empty($infile))
        return "";

    // Get all text data.
    $transformations = array();
    $texts = array();

    // Get the list of all objects.
    preg_match_all("#obj[\n|\r](.*)endobj[\n|\r]#ismU", $infile . "endobj\r", $objects);
    $objects = @$objects[1];

    // Select objects with streams.
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($objects); $i++) {
        $currentObject = $objects[$i];

        // Prevent time-out
        @set_time_limit ();
        if($this->showprogress) { //                              echo ". ";
            flush(); ob_flush();
        }

        // Check if an object includes data stream.
        if (preg_match("#stream[\n|\r](.*)endstream[\n|\r]#ismU", $currentObject . "endstream\r", $stream )) {
            $stream = ltrim($stream[1]);
            // Check object parameters and look for text data.
            $options = $this->getObjectOptions($currentObject);

            if (!(empty($options["Length1"]) && empty($options["Type"]) && empty($options["Subtype"])) )
            if ( $options["Image"] && $options["Subtype"] )
            if (!(empty($options["Length1"]) &&  empty($options["Subtype"])) )
                continue;

            // Hack, length doesnt always seem to be correct
            unset($options["Length"]);

            // So, we have text data. Decode it.
            $data = $this->getDecodedStream($stream, $options);

            if (strlen($data)) {
                if (preg_match_all("#BT[\n|\r](.*)ET[\n|\r]#ismU", $data . "ET\r", $textContainers)) {
                    $textContainers = @$textContainers[1];
                    $this->getDirtyTexts($texts, $textContainers);
                } else
                    $this->getCharTransformations($transformations, $data);
            }
        }
    }

    // Analyze text blocks taking into account character transformations and return results.
    $this->decodedtext = $this->getTextUsingTransformations($texts, $transformations);
}


function decodeAsciiHex($input) {
    $output = "";

    $isOdd = true;
    $isComment = false;

    for($i = 0, $codeHigh = -1; $i < strlen($input) && $input[$i] != '>'; $i++) {
        $c = $input[$i];

        if($isComment) {
            if ($c == '\r' || $c == '\n')
                $isComment = false;
            continue;
        }

        switch($c) {
            case '\0': case '\t': case '\r': case '\f': case '\n': case ' ': break;
            case '%':
                $isComment = true;
                break;

            default:
                $code = hexdec($c);
                if($code === 0 && $c != '0')
                    return "";

                if($isOdd)
                    $codeHigh = $code;
                else
                    $output .= chr($codeHigh * 16 + $code);

                $isOdd = !$isOdd;
                break;
        }
    }

    if($input[$i] != '>')
        return "";

    if($isOdd)
        $output .= chr($codeHigh * 16);

    return $output;
}

function decodeAscii85($input) {
    $output = "";

    $isComment = false;
    $ords = array();

    for($i = 0, $state = 0; $i < strlen($input) && $input[$i] != '~'; $i++) {
        $c = $input[$i];

        if($isComment) {
            if ($c == '\r' || $c == '\n')
                $isComment = false;
            continue;
        }

        if ($c == '\0' || $c == '\t' || $c == '\r' || $c == '\f' || $c == '\n' || $c == ' ')
            continue;
        if ($c == '%') {
            $isComment = true;
            continue;
        }
        if ($c == 'z' && $state === 0) {
            $output .= str_repeat(chr(0), 4);
            continue;
        }
        if ($c < '!' || $c > 'u')
            return "";

        $code = ord($input[$i]) & 0xff;
        $ords[$state++] = $code - ord('!');

        if ($state == 5) {
            $state = 0;
            for ($sum = 0, $j = 0; $j < 5; $j++)
                $sum = $sum * 85 + $ords[$j];
            for ($j = 3; $j >= 0; $j--)
                $output .= chr($sum >> ($j * 8));
        }
    }
    if ($state === 1)
        return "";
    elseif ($state > 1) {
        for ($i = 0, $sum = 0; $i < $state; $i++)
            $sum += ($ords[$i] + ($i == $state - 1)) * pow(85, 4 - $i);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $state - 1; $i++) {
            try {
                if(false == ($o = chr($sum >> ((3 - $i) * 8)))) {
                    throw new Exception('Error');
                }
                $output .= $o;
            } catch (Exception $e) { /*Dont do anything*/ }
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

function decodeFlate($data) {
    return @gzuncompress($data);
}

function getObjectOptions($object) {
    $options = array();

    if (preg_match("#<<(.*)>>#ismU", $object, $options)) {
        $options = explode("/", $options[1]);
        @array_shift($options);

        $o = array();
        for ($j = 0; $j < @count($options); $j++) {
            $options[$j] = preg_replace("#\s+#", " ", trim($options[$j]));
            if (strpos($options[$j], " ") !== false) {
                $parts = explode(" ", $options[$j]);
                $o[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
            } else
                $o[$options[$j]] = true;
        }
        $options = $o;
        unset($o);
    }

    return $options;
}

function getDecodedStream($stream, $options) {
    $data = "";
    if (empty($options["Filter"]))
        $data = $stream;
    else {
        $length = !empty($options["Length"]) ? $options["Length"] : strlen($stream);
        $_stream = substr($stream, 0, $length);

        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == "ASCIIHexDecode")
                $_stream = $this->decodeAsciiHex($_stream);
            elseif ($key == "ASCII85Decode")
                $_stream = $this->decodeAscii85($_stream);
            elseif ($key == "FlateDecode")
                $_stream = $this->decodeFlate($_stream);
            elseif ($key == "Crypt") { // TO DO
            }
        }
        $data = $_stream;
    }
    return $data;
}

function getDirtyTexts(&$texts, $textContainers) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($textContainers); $j++) {
        if (preg_match_all("#\[(.*)\]\s*TJ[\n|\r]#ismU", $textContainers[$j], $parts))
            $texts = array_merge($texts, array(@implode('', $parts[1])));
        elseif (preg_match_all("#T[d|w|m|f]\s*(\(.*\))\s*Tj[\n|\r]#ismU", $textContainers[$j], $parts))
            $texts = array_merge($texts, array(@implode('', $parts[1])));
        elseif (preg_match_all("#T[d|w|m|f]\s*(\[.*\])\s*Tj[\n|\r]#ismU", $textContainers[$j], $parts))
            $texts = array_merge($texts, array(@implode('', $parts[1])));
    }

}

function getCharTransformations(&$transformations, $stream) {
    preg_match_all("#([0-9]+)\s+beginbfchar(.*)endbfchar#ismU", $stream, $chars, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    preg_match_all("#([0-9]+)\s+beginbfrange(.*)endbfrange#ismU", $stream, $ranges, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($chars); $j++) {
        $count = $chars[$j][1];
        $current = explode("\n", trim($chars[$j][2]));
        for ($k = 0; $k < $count && $k < count($current); $k++) {
            if (preg_match("#<([0-9a-f]{2,4})>\s+<([0-9a-f]{4,512})>#is", trim($current[$k]), $map))
                $transformations[str_pad($map[1], 4, "0")] = $map[2];
        }
    }
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($ranges); $j++) {
        $count = $ranges[$j][1];
        $current = explode("\n", trim($ranges[$j][2]));
        for ($k = 0; $k < $count && $k < count($current); $k++) {
            if (preg_match("#<([0-9a-f]{4})>\s+<([0-9a-f]{4})>\s+<([0-9a-f]{4})>#is", trim($current[$k]), $map)) {
                $from = hexdec($map[1]);
                $to = hexdec($map[2]);
                $_from = hexdec($map[3]);

                for ($m = $from, $n = 0; $m <= $to; $m++, $n++)
                    $transformations[sprintf("%04X", $m)] = sprintf("%04X", $_from + $n);
            } elseif (preg_match("#<([0-9a-f]{4})>\s+<([0-9a-f]{4})>\s+\[(.*)\]#ismU", trim($current[$k]), $map)) {
                $from = hexdec($map[1]);
                $to = hexdec($map[2]);
                $parts = preg_split("#\s+#", trim($map[3]));

                for ($m = $from, $n = 0; $m <= $to && $n < count($parts); $m++, $n++)
                    $transformations[sprintf("%04X", $m)] = sprintf("%04X", hexdec($parts[$n]));
            }
        }
    }
}
function getTextUsingTransformations($texts, $transformations) {
    $document = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($texts); $i++) {
        $isHex = false;
        $isPlain = false;

        $hex = "";
        $plain = "";
        for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($texts[$i]); $j++) {
            $c = $texts[$i][$j];
            switch($c) {
                case "<":
                    $hex = "";
                    $isHex = true;
                    $isPlain = false;
                    break;
                case ">":
                    $hexs = str_split($hex, $this->multibyte); // 2 or 4 (UTF8 or ISO)
                    for ($k = 0; $k < count($hexs); $k++) {

                        $chex = str_pad($hexs[$k], 4, "0"); // Add tailing zero
                        if (isset($transformations[$chex]))
                            $chex = $transformations[$chex];
                        $document .= html_entity_decode("&#x".$chex.";");
                    }
                    $isHex = false;
                    break;
                case "(":
                    $plain = "";
                    $isPlain = true;
                    $isHex = false;
                    break;
                case ")":
                    $document .= $plain;
                    $isPlain = false;
                    break;
                case "\\":
                    $c2 = $texts[$i][$j + 1];
                    if (in_array($c2, array("\\", "(", ")"))) $plain .= $c2;
                    elseif ($c2 == "n") $plain .= '\n';
                    elseif ($c2 == "r") $plain .= '\r';
                    elseif ($c2 == "t") $plain .= '\t';
                    elseif ($c2 == "b") $plain .= '\b';
                    elseif ($c2 == "f") $plain .= '\f';
                    elseif ($c2 >= '0' && $c2 <= '9') {
                        $oct = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#", "", substr($texts[$i], $j + 1, 3));
                        $j += strlen($oct) - 1;
                        $plain .= html_entity_decode("&#".octdec($oct).";", $this->convertquotes);
                    }
                    $j++;
                    break;

                default:
                    if ($isHex)
                        $hex .= $c;
                    elseif ($isPlain)
                        $plain .= $c;
                    break;
            }
        }
        $document .= "\n";
    }

    return $document;
}}?>
```